# MGWT scrollpanel issue in ios8

Tags: gwt, scroll, ios8, mgwt

I'm developing an app using gwt,mgwt and gwtphonegap. My device having ios8. My scrollpanel containing some textfields and some list boxes.After appearing of keyboard or drop down if I tried to scroll the background scrollpanel, it is scrolling up/down, but not going back to the top(not going to initial scrollpanel position) when I release my finger. This happens only after firing of keyboard/dropdown. Is there workaround for this. please suggest me to resolve this.